# difference between mutex_init and DEFINE_MUTEX

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, locking, concurrency

I am using mutex lock in my kernel code. In linux/mutex.h, I came across following:

```
#define DEFINE_MUTEX(mutexname) \
         struct mutex mutexname = __MUTEX_INITIALIZER(mutexname)

 extern void __mutex_init(struct mutex *lock, const char *name,
                          struct lock_class_key *key);
```

What is the difference between two when they both seem to initialize mutex for use or are they completely different and I misunderstood? In my code, I just used `DEFINE_MUTEX` and started using it straight away, never bothered to use `__mutex_init`. How to check if the lock the way I used is correctly implemented? `MUTEX_INITIALIZER` is defined as:

```
#define __MUTEX_INITIALIZER(lockname) \
                 { .count = ATOMIC_INIT(1) \
                 , .wait_lock = __SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED(lockname.wait_lock) \
                 , .wait_list = LIST_HEAD_INIT(lockname.wait_list) \
                 __DEBUG_MUTEX_INITIALIZER(lockname) \
                 __DEP_MAP_MUTEX_INITIALIZER(lockname) }
```

Do we necessarily need to have them both in order to mutex work properly? Thanks.

Comment: Actually you are supposed to call `mutex_init` (without underscores. The difference is really clear: how do you suggest to initialize struct mutex  that was allocated from heap?

Answer (score 6):

`DEFINE_MUTEX` *defines* and *initializes* mutex. It is useful for define global mutexes.

`mutex_init` *initializes* already allocated mutex. It is used for per-object mutexes, when mutex is just a field in a heap-allocated object.

Any of these methods is *sufficient* for initialize mutex.

---

If you curious about difference in implementation of these methods(one with simple assignment, but another needs to call non-inlined function), then reason is `lockdep` tool. This debugging tool helps in revealing incorrect locks usage, which *may* lead to deadlock. The tool requires **static key** to be assigned for every lock object. Key for **global** mutex is **mutex object itself**, but key for **heap-allocated** mutex is **some(internal) static variable**, which is created for every usage of `mutex_init()` in the code.